# Unknown column error in Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana

I upgraded my application from Koahana 3.0.1 to Kohana 3.3. It works correctly in Koahana 3.0.1. But, in Kohana 3.3, I'm getting unknown column error. Below is the query I'm using in business model.

```
$biz = $this->where('business.id','IN',$arr)
       ->join('users','LEFT') 
   ->select(array('users.id','u'))
   ->on('users.business_id','=','business.id')  
   ->find_all();
```

The table names are businesses and users. The model is defined as

```
class Model_Business extends ORM
```

The error says -

Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'businesses.id' in 'where clause'

I could fix this(by updating as above) but, now  new error I got is -  "Method find() cannot be called on loaded objects".

It looks we can not use find_all() in model itself. In my current project, we return the results from model for all the queries. That means, upgrading will need to change almost all code.  Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: looks like your businesses -> business alias is causing the problem for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with businesses.id?

Comment: businesses was casing the issue...I could fix it, but soon I found there are major changes in both the versions and upgrading was as good as writing the same code for latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Since Kohana 3.1, the ORM fields always return the alias name. If it's a `$_has_many`, it's plural, if it's a `$_has_one` or `$_belongs_to`, it's singular. If you want to ensure the model name, set `$_object_name` to your desired value